# Calculate means of rows

Tags: r, row, average, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe called `ants` detailing multiple entries per site, looks like this:

```
  Site     Date     Time  Temp SpCond Salinity Depth Turbidity Chlorophyll
1   71 6/8/2010 14:50:35 14.32  49.88    32.66 0.397       0.0         1.3
2   71 6/8/2010 14:51:00 14.31  49.94    32.70 1.073       0.0         2.0
3   71 6/8/2010 14:51:16 14.32  49.95    32.71 1.034      -0.1         1.6
4   71 6/8/2010 14:51:29 14.31  49.96    32.71 1.030      -0.2         1.6
5   70 6/8/2010 14:53:55 14.30  50.04    32.77 1.002      -0.2         1.2
6   70 6/8/2010 14:54:09 14.30  50.03    32.77 0.993      -0.5         1.2
```

Sites have different numbers of entries, usually 3 but sometimes less or more. Where both date and site number match I would like to write a new dataframe with one entry per site detailing the average/mean readings for each parameter. I would like empty or "na" cells to be omitted from the calculation and subsequent dataframe.

I'm not sure if this is an apply function or a version of rowMeans maybe? Very stuck, any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete new answer with a full log also covering your new specification:

```
R> Lines <- "  Site     Date     Time  Temp SpCond Salinity Depth Turbidity Chlorophyll
+ 71 6/8/2010 14:50:35 14.32  49.88    32.66 0.397       0.0         1.3
+ 71 6/8/2010 14:51:00 14.31  49.94    32.70 1.073       0.0         2.0
+ 71 6/8/2010 14:51:16 14.32  49.95    32.71 1.034      -0.1         1.6
+ 71 6/8/2010 14:51:29 14.31  49.96    32.71 1.030      -0.2         1.6
+ 70 6/8/2010 14:53:55 14.30  50.04    32.77 1.002      -0.2         1.2
+ 70 6/8/2010 14:54:09 14.30  50.03    32.77 0.993      -0.5         1.2
+ "
R> con <- textConnection(Lines)
R> df <- read.table(con, sep="", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
R> close(con)
R> df$pt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(df$Date, df$Time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
R> library(plyr)
R> newdf <- ddply(df, .(Site,Date), function(x) mean(x[,-(1:3)], na.rm=TRUE))
R> newdf$pt <- as.POSIXct(newdf$pt, origin="1970-01-01")
R> newdf
  Site     Date  Temp SpCond Salinity  Depth Turbidity Chlorophyll                  pt
1   70 6/8/2010 14.30  50.03    32.77 0.9975    -0.350       1.200 2010-06-08 20:54:02
2   71 6/8/2010 14.32  49.93    32.70 0.8835    -0.075       1.625 2010-06-08 20:51:05
R>
```

Comment: You are AMAZING, sorry I was so totally stuck! This is great and makes much more sense to me now...THANK you!! And, yes this is ended now :)

Comment: You cannot imagine how many times I banged my own head against the wall on a) the factor/character thing, b) forgetting `as.POSIXct` after `strptime` and c) the darn `origin=` for the recast into `as.POSIXct`.  But luckily I have been at it long enough that *eventually* it stuck :)

Comment: And as an aside, that is one of the reason fully replicable examples are so much more useful in questions.  So don't just show `print(df)`, show code that generates or use `dput(df)` which serialises it compactly in ascii for recreation.

Answer (score 4):

Nico's answer looked like mine would have except that I would have added a named argument to be passed to mean() so that  the NA's (in the aggregated columns) would not sabotage the results. (I could not tell whether the OP was asking that NA's in the by variables or in the otehr variables were known or suspected of having NA's) :

```
aggregate(df, by=list(df$Site, df$Date), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You would probably need to also run aggregate or tapply calls in parallel to count the number of non-NA values.

The other method using aggregate's formula method might be different since na.action=na.omit is the default:

```
aggregate( . ~Site +Date, data=df,  FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using the [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) package and its `ddply()` function:

```
R> df
  Site     Date     Time  Temp SpCond Salinity Depth Turbidity Chlorophyll
1   71 6/8/2010 14:50:35 14.32  49.88    32.66 0.397       0.0         1.3
2   71 6/8/2010 14:51:00 14.31  49.94    32.70 1.073       0.0         2.0
3   71 6/8/2010 14:51:16 14.32  49.95    32.71 1.034      -0.1         1.6
4   71 6/8/2010 14:51:29 14.31  49.96    32.71 1.030      -0.2         1.6
5   70 6/8/2010 14:53:55 14.30  50.04    32.77 1.002      -0.2         1.2
6   70 6/8/2010 14:54:09 14.30  50.03    32.77 0.993      -0.5         1.2
R> library(plyr)
R> ddply(df, .(Site,Date), function(x) mean(x[,-(1:3)], na.rm=TRUE))
  Site     Date   Temp SpCond Salinity  Depth Turbidity Chlorophyll
1   70 6/8/2010 14.300 50.035   32.770 0.9975    -0.350       1.200
2   71 6/8/2010 14.315 49.933   32.695 0.8835    -0.075       1.625
R>
```

I used a custom anonymous function to skip the first three columns.

Comment: You need an `na.rm = TRUE` in your `mean` call there, Dirk

Comment: Thanks Dirk, this works fine except that'Time' column was missing from output so I amended it to: ddply(df, .(Site,Date), function(x) mean(x[,-(1:2)], na.rm=TRUE)) but this returns NA for values under 'Time', is it possible to average the time as well?

Comment: @Joey What value would average Time give you? The data pertain to the daily average.

Comment: I think you first need to combine date+time into a (parsed) POSIXct type. Over that you can average. You cannot average over what you have in Time now as it is text.  Which is why I skipped over it.

Comment: I see...then I shall try that. I thought it would come back to Posixct, haven't used that before but shall give it a go. Thank you :)

Comment: @Gavin Average time is important here as I may need to refer to tidal behaviour at the point at which the sample was taken as this is marine data.

Comment: @Joey: You wouldn't be spot sampling with a water quality sonde would you? (I'm a sort of limnologist.) If so I get what you mean - the data are not really sampled over the full day just short periods where the sonde captures multiple measurements. You'll need to combine the date and time fields into the Time column and then convert it to POSIXct, as Dirk remarks, then you can average it.

Comment: @Gavin: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing! :) I've data from a spot sonde and also a whole heap of data from a buoy sonde which records every 10secs continuously but I've not got onto the buoy data yet, I'm trying to format the spot sonde data first. I shall indeed try yours and Dirk's recommendation, it's not something I've done before so I'm going to go away to learn a bit more about "parsing" and "POSIXct"(?) before I can tackle this problem. Cheers for all your guys' help!

Comment: @Joey: By parsing, Dirk means paste the Date and Time together `df <- within(df, DateTime <- paste(Date, Time))`. Then you need to convert that combined `DateTime` into a POSIXct data type. Something like `df <- within(df, DateTime <- as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%d/%m%Y %H:%M:%S"))`. I think that will be the correct format for your dates/times. Then you can average `DateTime`. Not tested but hopefully will get you close.

Comment: @Gavin/Dirk: Works great up until I average the dataframe with the POSIXct DateTime column in. Returns some long and incoherent values, does such a column require special treatment in my ddply averaging code?

Comment: Make sure you have `as.POSIXct(strptime(pastedDateTime, "%d/%m/ ..."))` as you would get a POSIXlt (a list of 9 elements) instead. POSIXct is really just a supersmart numeric, and is your friend.

Comment: @Dirk: Thank you I tried what you suggested, I'll show you what I did, how do I insert code into a comment box?

Comment: Precede by a backtick, end with a backtick.  Or else just edit your question.

Comment: I'd do `df$posixt <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(df[,c("Date","Time")], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")))` and then include the new column in what you want averaged.

Comment: @Dirk: thanks! So, I parsed the Date and Time columns `antspar<-within(ants,DateTime<-paste(Date,Time))` then I converted with POSIXct `antspos<-within(antspar,DateTime<-as.POSIXct(strptime(DateTime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")))` Then I used you suggestion of `ddply()` function `avants<-ddply(antspos, .(Site.ID, Date, Time), function(x) mean(x[,-(1:3)], na.rm=TRUE))` But am still getting the 10digit line of numbers under my new DateTime column when I would dearly love to see a mean Time in there somewhere...any ideas? I don't think POSIXct wants to be my friend...

Comment: @Dirk: Thx for your suggestion, unfortunately this only returns `Error in .Internal(strptime(as.character(x), format, tz)) : 'format is missing` I thought averaging time would be fairly straight forward but apparently not :(

Comment: Please read up on strptime, as.POSIXct and play with it. I have used very similar steps numerous time.  And PLEASE stop this comment thread. If you have NEW strptime etc related questions (DO check the SO archives) post new quesions.

Comment: See the new answer I submitted.  Feel free to accept that as it seems to do what you asked.  I have been pretty patient with you here -- my off the cuff response used the wrong paste, and you have to ensure you paste character vectors not factors.  But my new answer should be fully replicable.  Can we end this now?  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df, by=list(df$Site, df$Date), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: ditto my comment to Dirk. You need to add `, na.rm = TRUE` after `FUN = mean` to exclude NA values.

Answer (score 2):

You were close with `rowMeans()`, but you need `colMeans()` instead. The others have shown how to use built-in or add-on functionality and I would certainly recommend you use them. However, it might be useful to see how to do something like this by hand:

```
## using df from Dirk's answer, we split the data in Site Date combinations
df.sp <- with(df,
              split(data.frame(Temp, SpCond, Salinity, Depth, Turbidity,
                               Chlorophyll),
                    list(Site = Site, Date = Date)))
## The above gives  a list of data frames one per date-site combo,
## to which we apply the colMeans() function
df.mean <- data.frame(t(sapply(df.sp, colMeans)))
```

At this point we need to do some extra tidying if you want the output to be nice like the others' answers:

```
## Process the rownames on df.mean
name.parts <- strsplit(rownames(df.mean), "\\.")
## pull out the Site part (before the '.')
df.mean <- within(df.mean, Site <- as.numeric(sapply(name.parts, `[`, 1)))
## pull out the Date part (after the '.')
df.mean <- within(df.mean, Date <- sapply(name.parts, `[`, 2))
## rearrange the columns
df.mean <- df.mean[, c(7:8,1:6)]
```

Note *again*, for most cases you should use the canned functions as described by the other answers. Sometimes it might be quicker to cook your own solution however, and the above might act as a guide to achieving this.