# Average and median of each n rows, for all columns of a dataframe, while keeping a datetime object as index

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, average

I have this quite complicate data in a data frame called ulyDataLefs60_12:

```
  Year Day Hour Min  Sec. E1.S1 E1.S2 E1.S3 E1.S4 E1.S5 E1.S6 E1.S7 E1.S8 E2.S1 E2.S2 E2.S3 E2.S4
1 2000 122    0   1 38.01  3.31 0.662 0.662  2.65  1.32 0.000 3.310  1.32 1.980 1.980 0.662 0.000
2 2000 122    0   1 50.10  1.98 3.310 1.980  1.98  1.98 1.320 4.630  1.32 1.320 0.662 0.000 3.310
3 2000 122    0   2  2.19  1.98 1.320 3.970  1.98  1.32 0.662 0.662  3.97 1.320 0.662 1.320 0.662
4 2000 122    0   2 14.28  2.65 1.320 2.650  3.31  2.65 1.320 3.970  2.65 2.650 0.000 0.662 2.650
5 2000 122    0   2 26.38  3.97 6.620 0.662  3.31  3.31 4.630 5.290  1.98 0.000 0.000 1.980 0.662
6 2000 122    0   2 38.47  2.65 0.662 3.310  1.98  1.32 1.980 1.980  2.65 0.662 1.320 1.980 1.320
  E2.S5 E2.S6 E2.S7 E2.S8 E3.S1 E3.S2 E3.S3 E3.S4 E3.S5 E3.S6 E3.S7 E3.S8 E4.S1 E4.S2 E4.S3 E4.S4
1 1.320  1.32  2.65 2.650 0.662 0.000 1.320 2.650 1.320 0.000 1.320 1.320 0.000 0.000 0.662 0.662
2 0.000  0.00  1.98 0.662 0.000 0.662 0.000 0.662 1.980 1.980 0.662 1.320 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.662
3 0.662  1.98  2.65 1.980 0.000 0.662 0.662 1.320 0.662 0.000 1.320 3.310 0.662 0.000 1.980 0.662
4 0.662  1.32  1.32 0.662 0.000 0.662 0.662 0.662 0.662 0.662 0.662 0.000 0.000 0.662 0.000 0.000
5 0.000  1.32  1.32 0.662 0.662 0.000 0.000 0.662 0.000 0.662 1.320 0.662 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.662
6 1.320  1.32  1.32 0.000 1.320 0.000 0.000 0.662 1.320 0.000 0.662 0.662 0.662 1.320 0.000 0.000
  E4.S5 E4.S6 E4.S7 E4.S8 FP5.S1 FP5.S2 FP5.S3 FP5.S4 FP5.S5 FP5.S6 FP5.S7 FP5.S8 FP6.S1 FP6.S2
1 0.000 0.662 0.662 0.000  0.331      0  0.662  0.000  0.662      0  0.000  0.331      0  0.331
2 0.000 0.000 0.662 0.662  0.331      0  0.662  0.000  0.662      0  0.000  0.331      0  0.331
3 0.662 0.000 0.662 1.320  0.000      0  0.662  0.000  0.331      0  0.000  0.000      0  0.000
4 0.662 0.662 0.000 0.662  0.000      0  0.662  0.000  0.331      0  0.000  0.000      0  0.000
5 0.000 0.000 0.662 0.000  0.331      0  0.000  0.331  0.331      0  0.331  0.000      0  0.000
6 0.000 0.000 0.662 0.662  0.331      0  0.000  0.331  0.331      0  0.331  0.000      0  0.000
  FP6.S3 FP6.S4 FP6.S5 FP6.S6 FP6.S7 FP6.S8 FP7.S1 FP7.S2 FP7.S3 FP7.S4 FP7.S5 FP7.S6 FP7.S7 FP7.S8
1  0.331  0.000  0.000  0.000      0  0.000      0  0.331  0.331  0.662      0  0.000  0.331  0.000
2  0.331  0.000  0.000  0.000      0  0.000      0  0.331  0.331  0.662      0  0.000  0.331  0.000
3  0.662  0.000  0.662  0.000      0  0.331      0  0.000  0.000  0.331      0  0.000  0.000  0.000
4  0.662  0.000  0.662  0.000      0  0.331      0  0.000  0.000  0.331      0  0.000  0.000  0.000
5  0.000  0.662  0.000  0.992      0  0.000      0  0.000  0.000  0.000      0  0.331  0.000  0.331
6  0.000  0.662  0.000  0.992      0  0.000      0  0.000  0.000  0.000      0  0.331  0.000  0.331
  PA.LEFS60S1 PA.LEFS60S2 PA.LEFS60S3 PA.LEFS60S4 PA.LEFS60S5 PA.LEFS60S6 PA.LEFS60S7 PA.LEFS60S8
1        64.2        52.0        70.9       105.0         144         170         134        96.2
2        62.6        49.5        68.8       104.0         142         168         134        95.4
3        62.7        47.7        66.2       101.0         140         167         135        96.5
4        62.4        46.3        64.4        99.3         138         166         135        96.7
5        59.9        43.7        63.2        98.8         138         164         133        94.8
6        62.3        45.7        63.7        98.7         137         166         136        96.9
    BX   BY   BZ Bmag....nT.  X            datetime
1 2.64 4.98 2.25        6.07 NA 2000-05-01 00:01:38
2 2.67 5.16 2.03        6.15 NA 2000-05-01 00:01:50
3 2.52 5.35 1.88        6.21 NA 2000-05-01 00:02:02
4 2.43 5.45 1.74        6.22 NA 2000-05-01 00:02:14
5 2.53 5.46 1.46        6.19 NA 2000-05-01 00:02:26
6 2.29 5.26 1.61        5.96 NA 2000-05-01 00:02:38

dput(head(ulyDataLefs60_12))
structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L
), Day = c(122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L), Hour = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Min = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Sec. = c(38.01, 
50.1, 2.19, 14.28, 26.38, 38.47), E1.S1 = c(3.31, 1.98, 1.98, 
2.65, 3.97, 2.65), E1.S2 = c(0.662, 3.31, 1.32, 1.32, 6.62, 0.662
), E1.S3 = c(0.662, 1.98, 3.97, 2.65, 0.662, 3.31), E1.S4 = c(2.65, 
1.98, 1.98, 3.31, 3.31, 1.98), E1.S5 = c(1.32, 1.98, 1.32, 2.65, 
3.31, 1.32), E1.S6 = c(0, 1.32, 0.662, 1.32, 4.63, 1.98), E1.S7 = c(3.31, 
4.63, 0.662, 3.97, 5.29, 1.98), E1.S8 = c(1.32, 1.32, 3.97, 2.65, 
1.98, 2.65), E2.S1 = c(1.98, 1.32, 1.32, 2.65, 0, 0.662), E2.S2 = c(1.98, 
0.662, 0.662, 0, 0, 1.32), E2.S3 = c(0.662, 0, 1.32, 0.662, 1.98, 
1.98), E2.S4 = c(0, 3.31, 0.662, 2.65, 0.662, 1.32), E2.S5 = c(1.32, 
0, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 1.32), E2.S6 = c(1.32, 0, 1.98, 1.32, 1.32, 
1.32), E2.S7 = c(2.65, 1.98, 2.65, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32), E2.S8 = c(2.65, 
0.662, 1.98, 0.662, 0.662, 0), E3.S1 = c(0.662, 0, 0, 0, 0.662, 
1.32), E3.S2 = c(0, 0.662, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0), E3.S3 = c(1.32, 
0, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0), E3.S4 = c(2.65, 0.662, 1.32, 0.662, 0.662, 
0.662), E3.S5 = c(1.32, 1.98, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 1.32), E3.S6 = c(0, 
1.98, 0, 0.662, 0.662, 0), E3.S7 = c(1.32, 0.662, 1.32, 0.662, 
1.32, 0.662), E3.S8 = c(1.32, 1.32, 3.31, 0, 0.662, 0.662), E4.S1 = c(0, 
0, 0.662, 0, 0, 0.662), E4.S2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.662, 0, 1.32), E4.S3 = c(0.662, 
0, 1.98, 0, 0, 0), E4.S4 = c(0.662, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0.662, 0
), E4.S5 = c(0, 0, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0), E4.S6 = c(0.662, 0, 0, 
0.662, 0, 0), E4.S7 = c(0.662, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0.662, 0.662), 
    E4.S8 = c(0, 0.662, 1.32, 0.662, 0, 0.662), FP5.S1 = c(0.331, 
    0.331, 0, 0, 0.331, 0.331), FP5.S2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    FP5.S3 = c(0.662, 0.662, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0), FP5.S4 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.331, 0.331), FP5.S5 = c(0.662, 0.662, 0.331, 0.331, 
    0.331, 0.331), FP5.S6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP5.S7 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.331, 0.331), FP5.S8 = c(0.331, 0.331, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), FP6.S1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP6.S2 = c(0.331, 0.331, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), FP6.S3 = c(0.331, 0.331, 0.662, 0.662, 0, 0), 
    FP6.S4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.662, 0.662), FP6.S5 = c(0, 0, 0.662, 
    0.662, 0, 0), FP6.S6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.992, 0.992), FP6.S7 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP6.S8 = c(0, 0, 0.331, 0.331, 0, 0), FP7.S1 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP7.S2 = c(0.331, 0.331, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP7.S3 = c(0.331, 
    0.331, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP7.S4 = c(0.662, 0.662, 0.331, 0.331, 
    0, 0), FP7.S5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP7.S6 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.331, 0.331), FP7.S7 = c(0.331, 0.331, 0, 0, 0, 0), FP7.S8 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.331, 0.331), PA.LEFS60S1 = c(64.2, 62.6, 62.7, 
    62.4, 59.9, 62.3), PA.LEFS60S2 = c(52, 49.5, 47.7, 46.3, 
    43.7, 45.7), PA.LEFS60S3 = c(70.9, 68.8, 66.2, 64.4, 63.2, 
    63.7), PA.LEFS60S4 = c(105, 104, 101, 99.3, 98.8, 98.7), 
    PA.LEFS60S5 = c(144, 142, 140, 138, 138, 137), PA.LEFS60S6 = c(170, 
    168, 167, 166, 164, 166), PA.LEFS60S7 = c(134, 134, 135, 
    135, 133, 136), PA.LEFS60S8 = c(96.2, 95.4, 96.5, 96.7, 94.8, 
    96.9), BX = c(2.64, 2.67, 2.52, 2.43, 2.53, 2.29), BY = c(4.98, 
    5.16, 5.35, 5.45, 5.46, 5.26), BZ = c(2.25, 2.03, 1.88, 1.74, 
    1.46, 1.61), Bmag....nT. = c(6.07, 6.15, 6.21, 6.22, 6.19, 
    5.96), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), datetime = structure(list(
        sec = c(38, 50, 2, 14, 26, 38), min = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
        year = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), wday = c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = c(121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
        121L, 121L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", 
    "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
    ), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("Year", "Day", 
"Hour", "Min", "Sec.", "E1.S1", "E1.S2", "E1.S3", "E1.S4", "E1.S5", 
"E1.S6", "E1.S7", "E1.S8", "E2.S1", "E2.S2", "E2.S3", "E2.S4", 
"E2.S5", "E2.S6", "E2.S7", "E2.S8", "E3.S1", "E3.S2", "E3.S3", 
"E3.S4", "E3.S5", "E3.S6", "E3.S7", "E3.S8", "E4.S1", "E4.S2", 
"E4.S3", "E4.S4", "E4.S5", "E4.S6", "E4.S7", "E4.S8", "FP5.S1", 
"FP5.S2", "FP5.S3", "FP5.S4", "FP5.S5", "FP5.S6", "FP5.S7", "FP5.S8", 
"FP6.S1", "FP6.S2", "FP6.S3", "FP6.S4", "FP6.S5", "FP6.S6", "FP6.S7", 
"FP6.S8", "FP7.S1", "FP7.S2", "FP7.S3", "FP7.S4", "FP7.S5", "FP7.S6", 
"FP7.S7", "FP7.S8", "PA.LEFS60S1", "PA.LEFS60S2", "PA.LEFS60S3", 
"PA.LEFS60S4", "PA.LEFS60S5", "PA.LEFS60S6", "PA.LEFS60S7", "PA.LEFS60S8", 
"BX", "BY", "BZ", "Bmag....nT.", "X", "datetime"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And what I want, is to get the average and median of a certain number of rows. Lets say, I want a new data frame, that instead of all these values, has the average or median of every 5 rows in all columns (or at least in all columns starting at the E1.S1 column.

I started by looking at the example: [Calculate means of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299362/calculate-means-of-rows) and it did get me so far as being able to get the average of a N number of rows for a single column of my dataframe.

```
ulyDataLefs60_12_avg = colSums(matrix(ulyDataLefs60_12$E1.S1, nrow=5))
```

The problem is that the R function I wanted to use, **colSums**, doesn't work with some fields, namely the datetime field (for obvious reasons), so I can't apply it across all the columns and get a nice averaged dataframe.

```
ulyDataLefs60_12_avg = colSums(matrix(ulyDataLefs60_12, nrow=5))
Error in colSums(matrix(ulyDataLefs60_12, nrow = 5)) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

I'm glad to have the datetime field at the beginning of the every 5 rows I use to get the average and the median (better if I got the datetime at the center of the 5 values interval tough), but so far I didn't come with an answer that does the 2 things at the same time.

Perhaps it's a really easy thing to do, but it's cracking my head.

Comment: @agstudy Cause like the title and the problem clearly states, I need a new dataframe with 1/5 of the values of the original with the average by every 5 rows, not for all the rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this data:

```
> dput(df)
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L
), Day = c(122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L), Hour = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Min = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Sec. = c(38.01, 
50.1, 2.19, 14.28, 26.38, 38.47), E1.S1 = c(3.31, 1.98, 1.98, 
2.65, 3.97, 2.65), E1.S2 = c(0.662, 3.31, 1.32, 1.32, 6.62, 0.662
), E1.S3 = c(0.662, 1.98, 3.97, 2.65, 0.662, 3.31), E1.S4 = c(2.65, 
1.98, 1.98, 3.31, 3.31, 1.98), E1.S5 = c(1.32, 1.98, 1.32, 2.65, 
3.31, 1.32), E1.S6 = c(0, 1.32, 0.662, 1.32, 4.63, 1.98), E1.S7 = c(3.31, 
4.63, 0.662, 3.97, 5.29, 1.98), E1.S8 = c(1.32, 1.32, 3.97, 2.65, 
1.98, 2.65), E2.S1 = c(1.98, 1.32, 1.32, 2.65, 0, 0.662), E2.S2 = c(1.98, 
0.662, 0.662, 0, 0, 1.32), E2.S3 = c(0.662, 0, 1.32, 0.662, 1.98, 
1.98), E2.S4 = c(0, 3.31, 0.662, 2.65, 0.662, 1.32)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Day", "Hour", "Min", "Sec.", "E1.S1", "E1.S2", "E1.S3", "E1.S4", 
"E1.S5", "E1.S6", "E1.S7", "E1.S8", "E2.S1", "E2.S2", "E2.S3", 
"E2.S4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

This works:

```
lapply(split(df, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(df)) / 5)), colMeans)
# $`1`
#      Year       Day      Hour       Min      Sec.     E1.S1     E1.S2     E1.S3     E1.S4     E1.S5     E1.S6     E1.S7 
# 2000.0000  122.0000    0.0000    1.6000   26.1920    2.7780    2.6464    1.9848    2.6460    2.1160    1.5864    3.5724 
#     E1.S8     E2.S1     E2.S2     E2.S3     E2.S4 
#    2.2480    1.4540    0.6608    0.9248    1.4568 
# 
# $`2`
#     Year      Day     Hour      Min     Sec.    E1.S1    E1.S2    E1.S3    E1.S4    E1.S5    E1.S6    E1.S7    E1.S8 
# 2000.000  122.000    0.000    2.000   38.470    2.650    0.662    3.310    1.980    1.320    1.980    1.980    2.650 
#    E2.S1    E2.S2    E2.S3    E2.S4 
#    0.662    1.320    1.980    1.320 
#
```

Then you can just `bind` them:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(df)) / 5)), colMeans))
#   Year Day Hour Min   Sec. E1.S1  E1.S2  E1.S3 E1.S4 E1.S5  E1.S6  E1.S7 E1.S8 E2.S1  E2.S2  E2.S3  E2.S4
# 1 2000 122    0 1.6 26.192 2.778 2.6464 1.9848 2.646 2.116 1.5864 3.5724 2.248 1.454 0.6608 0.9248 1.4568
# 2 2000 122    0 2.0 38.470 2.650 0.6620 3.3100 1.980 1.320 1.9800 1.9800 2.650 0.662 1.3200 1.9800 1.3200
```

Note: It also helps to check if all the columns you want to take `mean` of are either `integers` or `numeric` by doing:

```
> sapply(df, class)
#      Year       Day      Hour       Min      Sec.     E1.S1     E1.S2     E1.S3     E1.S4     E1.S5     E1.S6     E1.S7 
# "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
#     E1.S8     E2.S1     E2.S2     E2.S3     E2.S4 
# "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

**Edit:** Following OP's comment:

```
idx <- ceiling(seq_len(nrow(dd)) / 5)
# do colMeans on all columns except last one.
res <- lapply(split(dd[-(ncol(dd))], idx), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
# assign first value of "datetime" in each 5-er group as names to list
names(res) <- dd$datetime[seq(1, nrow(df), by=5)]
# bind them to give a matrix
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

Alternatively, if you want a `data.frame` *and* `datetime` as a *column*:

```
idx <- ceiling(seq_len(nrow(dd)) / 5)
res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dd[-(ncol(dd))], idx), 
                 colMeans, na.rm = TRUE)))
res$datetime <- dd$datetime[seq(1, nrow(dd), by=5)]
```

Comment: Hi. I get the error: `lapply(split(ulyDataLefs60_12, ceiling(seq_len(nrow(ulyDataLefs60_12)) / 5)), colMeans)
Error in as.matrix.data.frame(x) : 
  dims [product 375] do not match the length of object [379]`

Comment: I think it has something to do with the nRows of the frame not being a multiple of 5 perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it might be. But I thought I gave the factors right.. Let me check again. In the mean while, what does `sapply(ulyDataLefs60_12, class)` give  you?? (it should be numeric or integer as shown above)

Comment: Did you test on this data you've pasted? If so, can you provide a `dput` output? It'd be nice to test the data with the error...

Comment: It gives everything integer or numeric, except for : `> sapply(ulyDataLefs60_12, class)
$X
[1] "logical"
$datetime
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" ` I can do without the X, but I need the datetime to analyse the data.

Comment: There's no column "datetime" in the data you pasted.. Please post your "actual" data that gives error (using `dput` as shown in my post)

Comment: And yes, the test works in your data, but not in mine since it has the datetime object. I shouldn't be a problem of the nRows of the data then, since your example data also doesn't have nRows multiple of 5.

Comment: Yes, there is a datetime column in my data that I posted, you have to scroll the little window around the data I put in the problem since it doesn't fit it all at the same time. It's the last column by the way. I've added the dput command, like you asked (didn't know about it before).

Comment: What's the datetime you want for the mean of the 1st 5 rows for example?? They are all different...! Do you just want the year-month-day part...?

Comment: Well, the middle value would be perfect, but the starting value would also be good enough. I need the minutes and seconds as well, since the data varies a lot very quickly in some events.

Comment: @jbssm, try the edit. It takes the first date within each 5 rows.

Comment: And it works. At least the 2nd option you give. In the 1st one I get 2 good fields, but then all the index fields have NA as a value. Also, the 2nd version is much faster for me. Now I'll try to figure out how it works, but really, thank you very much for taking the time to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your data as a time series. Then using `xts` package you can use `period.apply` function

```
dat.xts <- xts(dat[,-ncol(dat)],dat$datetime)
## here I take every minutes because I don't have enouhgt data
## I think in your case 5 rows is equal to 5*12 mintues = 1 hour
pts <- endpoints(dat.xts,on='mins')
period.apply(dat.xts,pts,mean)

                   Year Day Hour Min   Sec.  E1.S1  E1.S2 E1.S3 E1.S4 E1.S5 E1.S6  E1.S7  E1.S8 E2.S1  E2.S2  E2.S3  E2.S4 E2.S5 E2.S6
2000-05-01 00:01:50 2000 122    0   1 44.055 2.6450 1.9860 1.321 2.315  1.65 0.660 3.9700 1.3200 1.650 1.3210 0.3310 1.6550 0.660 0.660
2000-05-01 00:02:38 2000 122    0   2 20.330 2.8125 2.4805 2.648 2.645  2.15 2.148 2.9755 2.8125 1.158 0.4955 1.4855 1.3235 0.661 1.485
```

**EDIT** show how to transform `xts` object to a `data.frame`:

To plot your data with `ggplot2` you need to coerce you xts object to a data.frame. For example you can do this:

```
  dat <- data.frame(date=index(dat.xts),coredata(dat.xts))
```

Then to plot E1.S1 vs date :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dat)+ 
 geom_line(aes(x=date,y=E1.S1))
```

Comment: Thank you. This xts seems very intuitive to work with timestamps. How do I use it to plot tough? I mean, in the original data, and from Arun answer, I could do: `qplot(datetime, E1.S1, data=ulyDataLefs60_12, geom="line")`
But what do I use here since there is no field named datetime?

Comment: I found the answer (trial/error method): `qplot(index(ddxts), E1.S1, data=ddxts, geom="line")`