# When calculating the mean and standard deviation, the columns with NA's values get NA in R

Tags: r

I am working with R.

My data look like this.

```
chair   table  hill  block  chain  ball  money house

  2       4     5      6      7      2     4     5 
  1       3     6      1      8     NA     9     1
  2       1    NA      6      1      8     2     3
  6       4     5      4      2      5     8     4
  5       5     5      5      3      2     6    NA
```

```
myFunc <- function(x) c(mean = mean(x),
                        n = length(x),
                        SD = sd(x))
```

When I calculate the mean and standard deviation values of each column I get the correct results for the columns that contain only numbers. However, for the columns that contains at least one NA I get an NA result for the mean and for the SD. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `mean` and `sd` have an argument `na.rm`. Set it to `TRUE`: `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to ignore the `NA` values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate means of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299362/calculate-means-of-rows)